# Sum of powers of a Matrix and the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a matrix, then for some $p$:

if $A^0+A^1+A^2+ \cdots +A^p = 0 $ then $A$ has an inverse

I have tried to prove this using:

- $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$
- $\det(A^n) = \det(A)^n$
- $\det(AB) = \det(A)\cdot\det(B)$

It shouldn't be difficult as it is a problem for first year in college, but I don't get any useful to prove it, can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mulitply the equation by $(I-A)$.

Comment: Thank you Kavi, I solve it with your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look directly for an inverse: Note that $A(-1(I+A+\cdots+A^{p-1})) = I$.